# How to increase the speed of loading sounds in Kivy [ANDROID]?

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am learning [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home) library to create games for android. After following the tutorials suggested by kivy documentation, I planned to create my own game: Rock Paper Scissors. I developed this game in almost two months. The game runs fine on PC as well as on android. But the problem which I am facing is related to its loading speed on android. It takes about 40 seconds for kivy to show the main menu on the screen! On some slower phones, the game doesn't even respond. I tried to figure out the reason for this problem. I found in kivy documentation that developers should use [Atlas](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.atlas.html) module to load images faster and decrease the overall loading time of the app. Thus, I applied **Atlas** in my game. But this didn't help.
Then, I tried other different things, like profiling, to check the cause of the long loading time. Although, I couldn't found anything helpful. Finally, I removed all the [SoundLoader](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.core.audio.html) statements from my code and doing this fixed the problem. The game loaded within 3-4 seconds.
After some more debugging, I found that the two background sounds of my game whose sizes are more than 2 MB are the reason for the long loading. I had already compressed these audios to make their size smaller, but still, they take a very long time to load on the memory. The other sounds (size in KBs) do not have any impact on the speed of loading.

So, I request you to tell me what should I do to make these two sounds load faster. I have uploaded the source code of this game on GitHub: https://github.com/devDiv629/Rock-Paper-Scissors. Line 18 and line 20 have the code for loading the sounds ([main.py](https://github.com/devDiv629/Rock-Paper-Scissors/blob/main/main.py)).
The APK of the game is also there in the releases. You can check out the loading time of the game by installing it on your mobile device.
Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have You seen [this issue](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2728)? I think it describes similar problem, and a workaround was using a different python module for playing sounds.

Comment: @sweak Thanks for the help! But using another module couldn't solve my problem. I just reduced the length of both the background music, which ultimately reduced their size. The game now loads 3x faster than before.

Comment: You have to determine which piece of hardware is the bottleneck. Is it the processor/RAM speed or is it the memory/storage capacity.
Do note, by compressing the sound file, you could be increasing the amount of processing required to decompress it. Compare that to a bigger file but with less decoding required.

Comment: @DarnellBaird Yes, I have tried using uncompressed audio files, both ogg and wav file formats. Using wav just increased the loading time very much, and ogg didn't have any great impact. And I think the processor speed is the problem, because on trying the game on phones with high processing power, the game loads much faster. In my opinion, the size of the audios is the core problem.